# Loading an image and passing it as icon to native code

Tags: react-native

In my app I want to load an image that later will used as `Foreground Notification` icon.

I do it like that:

```
const imagePath = require('path-to-image');
```

When I logged the value at `imagePath` I got the value `3`. What does it mean - is it like resource id?

Then I passed that imagePath to the native Java layer and used it to create the notification as such:

```
int resId = config.getNotificationIconPath(); // Here I take out the value that I passed
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(config.getNotificationTitle())
                .setContentText(config.getNotificationContent())
                .setSmallIcon(resId)
                .setContentIntent(mainActivityIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
```

However, when the service starts I don't see any icon on my status bar.
I guess my approach is wrong here.
How can I have an image loaded in the react-native layer and then to be used in the Java layer?